# A value of type 'List<News>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<News>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

```
Future<List<News>> getNews() async {
  final Url =
      "https://api.stockdata.org/v1/news/all?symbols=&filter_entities=true&language=en&api_token=api_token&countries=";
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(Url));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    return jsonResponse.map((data) => News.fromJSON(data)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception("Unexpected error occurred!");
  }
}
```

```
class News {
  final String title;
  final String desc;
  final String imgURL;
  final String url;

  News(
      {required this.title,
      required this.desc,
      required this.imgURL,
      required this.url});

  factory News.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return News(
        title: json["title"],
        desc: json["description"],
        imgURL: json["image_url"],
        url: json["url"]);
  }
}
```

```
FutureBuilder<List<News>>(
              future: futureNews,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<News> data = snapshot.data;      -----> Error
                  return ListView.builder(),
```

I am trying to build a News widget for stocks using the Stockdata API, which send the data in JSON format, but I keep getting the error:

```
A value of type 'List<News>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<News>'.
```

The error occurs in the List data = snapshot.data;

Can anyone help me with the same please?

Comment: what line display the error?

Comment: The List<News> data = snapshot.data; line

Answer (score 0):

Can you try update `List<News> data = snapshot.requireData;` ?

Comment: That did solve my error but now I'm getting a new error :')

Comment: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Comment: I think this error at `List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);` 
you can try cast: `json.decode(response.body) as List` ?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: can you share the line you ge error ?

Comment: The error is because of the snapshot.hasData being false